# Point existing code to new location of the remote respository in GIT

Tags: git, push

I moved my remote repository (`git`) on the server and the path changed. But, by mistake I had committed a few changes but forgot to `push` the last commit. Now when pushing  it is still trying at the old location.

How can i start pointing the same local code base to the new git repository so that i can continue working without having to re-clone the repository and re-apply the un-pushed changes?

> git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master
>
> remote: Not Found
>
> fatal: repository 'http://server.com/username/repo-name.git/' not
>   found

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use below command to change the link to new remote

> git remote set-url origin {NEW URL.git}

you could verify this change by

> git remote -v

The above commands assume that the remote repository is named as "origin", which is the default nomenclature using git, you can make suitable change based on your local environment.

More details can be found at https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Comment: Thanks ... this is safer than how i did it.

Comment: @rashmirathi: congrats on your first accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself:

Needed to manually change the `url` field in the `config` file under `.git` folder. It is a hidden folder (I knew, but did not think of earlier as i did not see it).

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://server.com/new-value/repo-name.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Now the code is pointed to the new repository location and i was able to push

Comment: in general; I would avoid messing with the .git/config file. There are commands for that; use `git remote set-url origin` as in @rashmirathi s answer

Comment: agree ... i just did the first thing i found as it was a but urgent. using the command is definitely a safe way.